# PHP y MySQL dos columnas referenciadas a una columna de distintas tablas

Tags: php, mysql, inner

Tengo un problema que no logro resolver en el cual realizo una consulta a una DB con php y mysql.
Desde una tabla tengo dos columnas que se relacionan con la columna de otra tabla.

Tabla1 
`Fecha | IdOficina1 | IdOficina2`

Tabla2 
`IdOficina | NombreOficina`

En la tabla 1 se guarda la fecha y el id de la oficina por la que ingresa y la oficina por la que se retira un documento y en la tabla 2 se indica el id y nombre de la oficina usando la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT Tabla1.*, Tabla2.IdOficina <br>
FROM Tabla1<br>
INNER JOIN Tabla2 ON Tabla1.IdOficina1  = Tabla2.NombreOficina<br>
INNER JOIN Tabla2 ON Tabla1.IdOficina2  = Tabla2.NombreOficina;<br>
```

Al realizar la consulta desde PHP me indica el error

> "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in... line 133", la cual corresponde a "if ($result->num_rows > 0)".

¿Alguien podrá ayudarme e indicarme dónde está el problema?. Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo!.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Estas haciendo los join mal tienes que igualarlos con los mismos datos en ambas tablas, me hago entender, tienes que relacionarlos por el id de cada uno

Tabla1
Fecha | IdOficina1 | IdOficina2

Tabla2
IdOficina1 | NombreOficina

select * from Tabla1 as t1 join Tabla2 as t2 on t1.IdOficina1 = t2.IdOficina1

recuerda que para unir dos tablas de esta forma debes tener los mismo datos en id para que se pueda correlacionar

aquí puedes aprender mas:
http://www.edu4java.com/es/sql/sql5.html
saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder.Lo intenté como me indicas pero al imprimir las oficinas lo hace con el mismo nombre siendo que tienen distinto ID, es decir, debería imprimir en php en oficina de entrada: Oficina A y en oficina de salida: Oficina B, pero ambas se imprimen como oficina A. Voy a leer el link que me has dejado. Nuevamente gracias.

Comment: @MarcosGonzález recuerda que aqui en el esquema que mostraste no mas esta en nombre de oficina relacionada con oficiana1 o oficinaA, no se que tablas quieras relacionar, pero si tienes otra tabla donde este la oficinaB relacionala con el id de la primera tabla.... si quieres datos de los nombres en especificos, mencionas el alias que asignaste y el nombre de la columna